# Unexpected gl_stack_underflow error

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on a small game which uses OpenGL.

I was getting a gl_stack_underflow error. I have gone through the code, and there is one glPushMatrix for each glPopMatrix. Any ideas what else could be causing this error?

Comment: Please post the code that's causing the error, and all the details of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Did you maybe do a

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
/* ... */
glPushMatrix();
```

"balanced" by a

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
/* ... */
glPopMatrix();
```

It matters which matrix is active at the time of push/pop operation.

Anyway, you shouldn't use the OpenGL built-in matrix operations at all. Use something like GLM, Eigen or linmath.h to build the matrices as part of your programs data structures and just load the matrices you require with `glLoadMatrix` or, when you finally go for shaders, `glUniform`.

No, OpenGL built-in matrix operations are *not* GPU accelerated, so there's no benefit at all in using them.

Comment: A feat of psychic debugging!